# how to remove rows and cols from main matrix after SVD function?

Tags: c#, matlab, mathnet-numerics

I have :

```
 A =
 1     2     3
 2     4     5
 5     5     5
```

and

```
[U S V]=svd(A)
```

How can I remove the dimension of A matrix from SVD function?

Comment: So you want to find the SVD of a reduced dimension matrix `A`?

Comment: yes . i need find relation between A matrix and S matrix after SVD(A).

Comment: Removing rows and columns from a matrix after SVD doesn't make any sense to me.  Did you perhaps want to find a **lower-rank** approximation to `A` after removing singular values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to get a reduced version of the matrix `A`.

This is done by using `PCA`, search it. For example, if you want the reduced matrix `A` to have `K` dimensions:

```
[m, ~] = size(A);

Sigma = 1.0/m .* A' * A;
[U, S, ~] = svd(Sigma);

newA = zeros(size(A, 1), K);

for i = 1:size(A, 1),
    for j = 1:K,
        x = A(i, :)';
        projection_k = x' * U(:, j);
        newA(i, j) = projection_k;
    end
end
end
```

So the matrix `newA` will be a reduced version of `A` with `K` dimensions.

It's better for you to search about `PCA`.

Comment: i have many dataset related ( social network system ) . i like user dataset reduced users and cols. i use this code in matlab but not work , error in K variable

Comment: K is the dimension. If your data has originally 10 dimentions and you wnat to reduce it to 2, K = 2. I think you don't know anything about PCA, better to study it than to just use the code.

Comment: can you call me on skype for help me , skypeid= tarraharshad